# Crontab executing script differently

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a script that checks if MySQL service is running on my Linux server.
If I run the script manually it works fine, but when crontab runs the script it gets different results..

This is my script:

```
#! /bin/sh

TODAY=$(/bin/date)

UP=$(/sbin/service mysql status| /bin/grep 'SUCCESS' | /usr/bin/wc -l);
if [ "$UP" -ne 1 ];
then
        echo "mysql not working, Date: $TODAY" >> /scripts/sql_log.txt;
        sudo /bin/mail -s "MySql is DOWN" mail@mail.com < /dev/null
        sudo /sbin/service mysql start  

else 
        echo "mysql is working, Date: $TODAY" >> /scripts/sql_log.txt;      
fi
```

I am using the full path of the commands..the only part that I do not understand 100% is:

```
if [ "$UP" -ne 1 ];
```

What is this -ne 1?

**So in this case MySQL is running:**
If I run the script manually it writes that MySQL is working in the log file.
But Crontab just write that MySQL is not running in the log file (even if it is running) and it does not send any mail or something

**If mysql service is stopped** and I run the script manually, it send me an email and start the service as it should...

Any idea?

Comment: Does your cron have premissions to run the service command? What I would probably do is set up a cron job with just `service mysql status`, which should mail you the output. Then you can check what it says. It might be something like `Permission Denied` or even `bash: service: command not found` Either way it should give you some hints.

Comment: Why it does not send an email: Probably your sudo call blocks, since it prompts for a password.

Comment: I just noticed that my `cron` works with a different `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Now it works..looks like that the problem was caused because I did not write the full path of the command..This is the script that I am using now and it is working:

```
#! /bin/sh
UP=$(/sbin/service mysql status| /bin/grep 'SUCCESS' | /usr/bin/wc -l);
if [ "$UP" -ne 1 ];
then
        sudo /bin/mail -s "MySql is DOWN" mail@mail.com < /dev/null
        sudo /sbin/service mysql start      
fi
```